Does a simple and intuitive theory have better chances of being true?
A lot of times we try to predict specific things by models that describe empirical results of other things.  For example how could Einstein predict that gravity is linked to relativity just by knowing that F=ma and E=mc², and the equivalence principle? Why did he think that the two things are related, if the fundamental rules of the universe are random and not necessarily intuitive?
There is no point in trying to predict things that seem to make sense to us just because they are related to other topics. Maybe Einstein just was lucky and he thought that it doesn't have to be right. But it may be the reasons those formulas are the way they are.
For example there are things we don't know and some physicists may think that they are true and some may think that they are not.
But the question is: why do they think it true or not? Do they have some statistics that tells them which event will be more surprising then the other? Or is it just in their minds? Does the intuition often turn to be right more than the chances of someone randomly guessing the correct explanation for some phenomenon?

Why do physicists think it is true? Because they have verified empirically. But those formulas are not "explanations", only a mathematical description. And they may be an approximation that will eventually be improved, by someone standing on Einstein's shoulders.

You are without any possible question looking for Feynman's The Character of Physical Law.

^^^^ This -- great book from a great theoretical mind.

A simple theory is more likely to be true, IF it fully matches all the observations.

@causative - except we never have all the possible observations. Newtons theory looks definitive till subtle issues popped up with light in 1800's. Sure, newtown's laws are "true" for all practical purposes (almost all engineering relies on thermodynamics, classical mechanics, and classical E&M)

What is the (1) question?

I read your post as two questions:
Q1: The headline "Does a simple and intuitive theory have better chances of being true?"
First, simple theories have fewer 'potential points of failure'. Complex theories involve a lot of moving parts that may be (reciprocally) interdependent. Testing such a theory through experiments is difficult. How do you know which part you got wrong when your observations disagree with the theory?
Furthermore, humans seem to value nonempirical features (superempirical virtues) of theories, e.g. simplicity, non-ad hocness, novel predictive power, elegance, and explanatory power (Ladyman 2012).
As an anecdote, my friends who work in theoretical computer science always seem to experience a certain 'yuk' moment when confronted with proofs generated by a computer program. The proof is correct, no doubt, but 100 pages long and not really traceable by humans. Humans like things that they can understand.
Q2: How to people come up with hypotheses / theories?
Philosopher of science Karl Popper wrote: "[T]he act of conceiving or inventing a theory seems to me neither to call for logical analysis nor to be susceptible to it . . . the question of how it happens that a new idea occurs . . . may be of great interest to empirical psychology; but it is irrelevant to the logical analysis of scientific knowledge."
He distinguished between working within the context of discovery and the context of justification. Theories are formulated in the former where 'anything goes'. You can have a dream, a vision from god, a drug-induced hallucination, a discussion with a colleague, or whatever else helps you to come up with hypotheses about the world. It is a creative process (which I personally find beautiful about science). However, when switching to the context of justification, you are bound by the conventions of the scientific method.

Please do read The Character of Physical Law as suggested by @gs -- great book!
There's a lot in your post but I think you are wondering what principles guide scientists to "truth". I particular, I see "simplicity" in your title and also a question related to relativity. I'll address simplicity first and then what I call the "Generalized Copernican Principle".
Simplicity
It's also called the principle of parsimony and is often misunderstood to be an absolute principle, when it is more of like a tiebreaker for two theories that both fit the data equally well. It's also not necessarily about truth but about epistemological humility/conservatism.
If two theories are equally good predictors, go with the one that has the fewest additional commitments. Why? Not because we think the simpler theory has everything right, but because the extra stuff we add to a theory is almost certainly going to be wrong if it is not essential to explaining the data.
For example, here are two possible formulations of Newton's second law:
(1) (total mass) F = ma or
(2) (effective mass) F = meffa ≡ (m+ - m-)a
Both can explain the data equally well. However, the effective mass theory has a more complex view of mass as akin to charge.
Which is a more accurate picture of reality?
Well, if we were back in Newton's day, we'd not have much of a basis for the added complexity of signed mass. However, upon the discovery of antimatter, there would be a justification for an observed mass being a balance of matter and antimatter (still wrong as antimatter still has mass).
So far, F=ma is still holding strong as we see no evidence that we ever observe two types of mass, even though we can accommodate such a notion in a more complex theory of classical dynamics.
Generalized Copernican Principle
The other principle I've seen be effectively used in science is the idea that "nothing is privileged": Humans are not the "most perfect organism", the earth is not the center of the solar system, the universe has no center at all, there is no privileged reference frame that defines absolute motion etc.
Einstein's thinking is along these lines: there is nothing special about acceleration vs being in a gravitational field.
I call this the Generalized Copernican Principle, and indeed this one does seem to track truth quite well.
Taken to the extreme, the completion of the Generalized Copernican Programme would posit some flavor of modal realism, which suggests that even our reality is not the reality but a reality. Even our universe isn't special - reality consists of everything that could ever happen because there is nothing there to prevent it (and it provides some nice theoretical properties -- not without cost ;)

There are 2 competing views:

Realism: Simply that scientific theories are not mere explanatory models, they're truths. So per this view, space actually is distorted by mass (relativity). Atoms really exist.

Save the phenomena: That scientific theories are nothing but explanatory models that work.  So heliocentrism is not necessarily true, it simply explains as much as geocentrism but is simpler.


Hilary Putnam's no miracles argument is worth a dekko.
You seem to have endorsed scientific realism (1). As for intuitive theory, how are you going to work that into your current belief, in combination with simple?

+1 The legend goes that Einstein saw his E=MC^2 in a dream.
Intuition is almost always an important part of great discoveries.
But, from the philosophical point of view, it would be hard to differentiate between common-false intuition and real gift-intuition we are possibly getting from outside our reality.

Si, Wikipedia has enough articles on intuition to underscore its importance. @TheMatrixEquation-balance
